# I can't remove a background image in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint 2007 document. There is this annoying background graphic in my Powerpoint slide. I know about slide master, but this little bugger is not something that I can delete from slide master. Argh!!!!

The graphic is a little pumpkin at the bottom of the slide and my company logo at the top.

http://www.violetonresumes.com/HelpMeRemoveThisGraphic.pptx

Here is a copy of the document. I've already lost two hours of my life on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: take it easy on the exclamation marks ;)

Comment: Yea, exclamation marks are people too!!!

Comment: In this case the exclamation marks are warranted. Terrible ui design: this function should be accessible via menus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it. Click on "View". Then click "Slide Master". You see on the left a series of panels stacked Vertically. The problem is that the graphics were in one of the panels above the panel that appeared first. I was going down but not up. Once I checked out the panels above I found the one with the annoying graphic.

Thanks

Comment: This is such a terrible usability issue. Why is that option not in the menus??? The user interface designers want us to click on every single thing on the page to find it??